# Django filter to check if there are any other booking between the given dates

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to make a hotel booking app. So I have two models, i.e., Room and Booking.

```
# models
class Room(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Booking(models.Model):
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    booked_for_datetime = models.DateTimeField()
    booked_till_datetime = models.DateTimeField()
```

I would like to inform if the room is unavailable when there is already another booking for the required room, or else if it is actually available then create a booking.

I am working with django rest framework, so I will have to apply these validation on the create and update method, maybe something like this:

```
# serializers

def roomAvailable(validated_data):
    available = False

    # ...
    # validation check here...
    # ...

    return available


class BookingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Booking
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        if roomAvailable(validated_data):
            return Booking.objects.create(**validated_data)
        else:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({
                "detail": "Room is not available for these dates."
            })

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        if roomAvailable(validated_data):
            ...
            instance.save()
        else:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({
                "detail": "Room is not available for these dates."
            })
        return instance
```

Eg:

Room 101 was already booked between 01-12-2019 to 04-12-2019.

I would like to block the booking if someone's trying to book the same room (101)

- between 29-11-2019 to 01-12-2019
- between 29-11-2019 to 02-12-2010
- between 30-11-2019 to 05-12-2019
- between 01-12-2019 to 04-12-2019
- between 02-12-2019 to 03-12-2019
- between 04-12-2019 to 07-12-2019

For now this is how I am filtering, but I am not sure if this is the best approach as I might be missing other bookings which will lead to double bookings, and maybe there is another way to approach this problem?

```
def roomAvailable(validated_data):
    available = True
    ...
    if room.booking_set.filter(
            Q(booked_till_datetime__date__gte=validated_data['booked_for_datetime'],
              booked_till_datetime__date__lte=validated_data['booked_till_datetime']) |

            Q(booked_for_datetime__date__gte=validated_data['booked_for_datetime'],
              booked_for_datetime__date__lte=validated_data['booked_till_datetime']) |

            Q(booked_for_datetime__date__gte=validated_data['booked_for_datetime'],
              booked_till_datetime__date__lte=validated_data['booked_till_datetime']) |

            Q(booked_for_datetime__date__lte=validated_data['booked_for_datetime'],
              booked_till_datetime__date__gte=validated_data['booked_till_datetime'])
    ).exists():
        available = False

    return available
```

Could you please help me how can I check if there are any booking between the new dates?

Answer (score 8):

### Short answer

```
start_date = '2019-11-29'
end_date = '2019-12-01'
filter_params = dict(booked_for_datetime__date__lte=end_date, booked_till_datetime__date__gte=start_date) # just for redability
is_occupied = Booking.objects.filter(**filter_params, room__name=101).exists()
```

**Notes**:
1. **`is_occupied`** will be a boolean
2. I have used the [**`date`** filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#date), since OP provided only **`date`**, not a **`datetime`**

---

### Explanation

[image]

Someone booked the room (101) between **01-12-2019** and **06-12-2019**, which is marked in *Red*. According to the conditions given in the OP, the available slots are marked in *Green*.

#### Logic

1. ***input "end time"*** should be less than ***available `booked_for_datetime__date`***
2. ***input "start time"*** should be greater than ***available `booked_till_datetime__date`***

### Shell output

```
In [2]: date_list = [ 
   ...:     dict(start='2019-11-29', end='2019-12-01'), 
   ...:     dict(start='2019-11-29', end='2019-12-02'), 
   ...:     dict(start='2019-11-30', end='2019-12-05'), 
   ...:     dict(start='2019-12-01', end='2019-12-04'), 
   ...:     dict(start='2019-12-02', end='2019-12-03'), 
   ...:     dict(start='2019-12-02', end='2019-12-04'), 
   ...:     dict(start='2019-12-03', end='2019-12-04'), 
   ...:     dict(start='2019-12-02', end='2019-12-05'), 
   ...:     dict(start='2019-12-04', end='2019-12-06'), 
   ...:     dict(start='2019-12-04', end='2019-12-07'), 
   ...:     dict(start='2019-12-06', end='2019-12-07'), 
   ...:     dict(start='2019-12-07', end='2019-12-10'), 
   ...:     dict(start='2019-11-29', end='2019-11-30'), 
   ...: ]                                                                                                                                                                                                          

In [3]:                                                                                                                                                                                                            

In [3]: Booking.objects.all()                                                                                                                                                                                      
Out[3]: <QuerySet [<Booking: Booking object (1)>]>

In [4]: Booking.objects.all()[0].__dict__                                                                                                                                                                          
Out[4]: 
{'_state': <django.db.models.base.ModelState at 0x7efee64d5a58>,
 'id': 1,
 'room_id': 1,
 'booked_for_datetime': datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 1, 2, 45, 9, tzinfo=<UTC>),
 'booked_till_datetime': datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 5, 2, 45, 8, tzinfo=<UTC>)}

In [5]: # booked the room from 01-12-2019 to 05-12-2019                                                                                                                                                            

In [6]: for date in date_list: 
   ...:     start_date, end_date = date.values() 
   ...:     filter_params = dict(booked_for_datetime__date__lte=end_date, booked_till_datetime__date__gte=start_date) 
   ...:     is_occupied = Booking.objects.filter(**filter_params, room__name=101).exists() 
   ...:     if is_occupied: 
   ...:         print('Not Available on this range, start: {} end: {}'.format(start_date, end_date)) 
   ...:     else: 
   ...:         print('Available on this range, start: {} end: {}'.format(start_date, end_date)) 
   ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                            
Not Available on this range, start: 2019-11-29 end: 2019-12-01
Not Available on this range, start: 2019-11-29 end: 2019-12-02
Not Available on this range, start: 2019-11-30 end: 2019-12-05
Not Available on this range, start: 2019-12-01 end: 2019-12-04
Not Available on this range, start: 2019-12-02 end: 2019-12-03
Not Available on this range, start: 2019-12-02 end: 2019-12-04
Not Available on this range, start: 2019-12-03 end: 2019-12-04
Not Available on this range, start: 2019-12-02 end: 2019-12-05
Not Available on this range, start: 2019-12-04 end: 2019-12-06
Not Available on this range, start: 2019-12-04 end: 2019-12-07
Available on this range, start: 2019-12-06 end: 2019-12-07
Available on this range, start: 2019-12-07 end: 2019-12-10
Available on this range, start: 2019-11-29 end: 2019-11-30
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than looking for the bookings that overlap the given date range, it's easier to exclude those that don't:

```py
def roomAvailable(validated_data):
    ...

    bookings = room.booking_set.exclude(
        booked_for_datetime__date__gt=validated_data['booked_till_datetime'],
    ).exclude(
        booked_till_datetime__date__lt=validated_data['booked_for_datetime'],
    )

    return not bookings.exists()
```

In this way you are basically **excluding from your queryset** those bookings that ***end before*** or **start after** the given date period, if there is any bookings that don't respect this condition, then the room is not available.

Note that the two conditions need to live in two different `exclude` to have an `OR` between them, if you put them together what you will obtain is an `AND`
which is not what you want.

Comment: Isn't this an AND anyway? if you have something `.excluded()` why would it be included?

Answer (score 0):

```py
def roomAvailable(validated_data):
    overlapping_booking_exists = Booking.objects.filter(
        (
            Q(booked_for_datetime__lte=validated_data["booked_for_datetime"])
            & Q(booked_till_datetime__gt=validated_data["booked_for_datetime"])
        ) | (
            Q(booked_for_datetime__lt=validated_data["booked_till_datetime"])
            & Q(booked_till_datetime__gte=validated_data["booked_till_datetime"])
        ),
        room_id=validated_data["room"]
    ).exists()

    return not overlapping_booking_exists
```

Answer (score -1):

first of All I suggest to use `DateField` instead of `DateTimeField`; if you're using PostgreSQL as DB you could also use [DateRangeField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#daterangefield).

This queryset is more or less what do you need

```
qs = Room.objects.exclude(
    booking__booked_for_datetime__lte=validated_data,
    booking__booked_till_datetime__gte=validated_data
)
```

If you need "just" to know if there're available rooms you can do

```
qs.Exists()
```

with

```
qs.values('id', 'name')
```

you get the `id` and `name` of all available rooms

Comment: I don't think you understood what my problem is. Could you please elaborate more.

Comment: the queryset I gave to you is generic (it provides info about all rooms, if you need just for one room you can do `qs.filter(room_id=my_room_id)`